# How to define a multi-level dictionary structure and insert data into that?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a multi-level Python dictionary using **defaultdict**.The structure of the dictionary is like below:

```
{
    "source1": {
        "gene": {
            "gene1": {
                "location": [
                    [
                        10,
                        200
                    ]
                ],
                "mrna": {
                    "1": {
                        "location": [
                            [
                                10,
                                200
                            ]
                        ],
                        "product": "hypothetical",
                        "CDS": {
                            "location": [
                                [
                                    10,
                                    50
                                ],
                                [
                                    100,
                                    200
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in this kind of cases in Python, we need to define the structure before inserting any data.

my try to define the structure is :

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(
        lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))))))
```

Now to insert data in the above structure, I am using below codes to create the above-defined format.

```
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['location'].append([10, 200])
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['location'].append(['10', '200'])
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['product'] = 'hypothetical' 
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['CDS']['location'].append([10, 50])
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['CDS']['location'].append([100, 200])
```

But I am getting some error. So can any one help me to create the multi-level dictionary?

Comment: How many times you have to hit the wall with your head in order to realize that you're running into a wall ?

Comment: @alfasin - is it not possible to do?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but do you really want to maintain code that's doing things like: `dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['CDS']['location'].append([100, 200])` ?

Comment: Yes, I  would like to maintain that structure. The **gene, gene1** will be variable in case of real data set. but here I am using only this two name for the better understanding

Comment: Good luck then!

Comment: looks like I need that as I am getting few down votes for this question

Comment: Your problem is much bigger than a few downvotes: you're asking a question but insist on not listening. This is *not* a good way to learn... As I said, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary definition is using other datatypes than those you want to add -
 (Also check ChristianFigueroas answere because of your spelling).

If I run your code i get the error `AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'`. This is why I created your dictionary with the right datatypes (excuse lazy me for using dictionaries instead of default dicts).

```python
dct = {}                                                    #Dict
dct['source1'] = {}                                         #Dict
dct['source1']['gene'] = {}                                 #Dict
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1'] = {}                        #Dict
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['location'] = []            #List
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna'] = {}                #Dict
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1'] = {}           #Dict
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['location'] = [] #List
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['product'] = ''  #String
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['CDS'] = {}    #Dict
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['CDS']['location'] = [] #List


dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['location'].append([10, 200])
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['location'].append(['10', '200'])
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['product'] = 'hypothetical'
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['CDS']['location'].append([10, 50])
dct['source1']['gene']['gene1']['mrna']['1']['CDS']['location'].append([100, 200])
```

I hope you see what I did there.

Answer (score 0):

The build-up of subdicts can be done automatically:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> f = lambda: defaultdict(f)
>>> d = f()
>>> d['usa']['texas'] = 'lone star'
>>> d['usa']['ohio'] = 'buckeye'
>>> d['canada']['alberta'] = 'flames'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the above dictionary will not able to hold any **list**. So can you please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're trying to get `dct["source1"]["gene"]["gene1"]["mrna"]["1"]["CDS"]["location"]` but there's no `"CDS"` key, just a `"cds"`. Replace the `"CDS"` with `"cds"`.

```
dct["source1"]["gene"]["gene1"]["mrna"]["1"]["cds"]["location"].append( ... )
```

Python keys are case-sensitive, so make sure you are matching the string *exactly*.

Also, I would recommend not putting your data into super specific `dict`s like that because then it gets harder to debug and actually see where something went wrong, like the case-sensitive `"CDS"` thing.